# Connection Strings error from the Web.config File in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i deployed the project through visual studio to a website hosting that support mvc and MS sql  too after that i edit the config.web with the connection string provided by database hosting and restore a database backup successfully
but there's some error in web.config file so the website didn't work properly related to database access but it works fine locally

this is a connection string from web,config file ( which works locally without errors)

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-wa3iny_pro_mvc-20140520172729;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-wa3iny_pro_mvc-20140520172729.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


<add name="wa3enyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=wa3eny;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and honestly this is a first time for me to deal with things related to deploy and publish project through website hosting so that i tried many things to correct the error related to connection string but i couldn't do that

this is a connection string from website hosting server ,config file

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5004.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_9B2DF3_wa3iny;User Id=YOUR_DB_name;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="wa3enyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=wa3eny;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

but there's some error here 
in first i didn't include the second connection string connection  wa3enyEntities

but the website hosting support told me that there's error 
("No connection string named 'wa3enyEntities' could be found in the application config file.)
so that i included it but the error still existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this coonection string and he work without any errors

http://pastie.org/9526738

thanks @parth shah for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have not updated your wa3enyEntities connection string. If you look at it carefully, you will see "provider connection string:..." which is still pointing to the default sql server instance.

Comment: i have used this connection string ( only )
     <add name="wa3enyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection  string=&quot;data source=SQL5004.myASP.NET;initial catalog=DB_9B2DF3_wa3iny;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />


but the error still exist
then added to it the first one " DefaultConnection"
but the error still existed

Comment: Can you remove "integrated security=false;" and replace it with "User Id=YOUR_DB_Name;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"? I highly doubt your application is using the Default Connection but if you are going to keep it, make sure both connection strings have the exact same value.